# Firebase Google Sign In - Users Not Getting Created in Authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I've been working on an application in which I want to implement a sign in with google feature along with creating a UID(unique ID) for that user. When going through the google pop-up to sign in, it works fine. However, when I check my firebase authentication, the user is not created (I'm not receiving any errors). I've tried changing my way of writing this code and researching, but they all come back to the same functions. I've also tried to use a different database, but it still didn't work. This is my code...

LoginScreen.js

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import {
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import {
  RFValue
} from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";
import firebase from "firebase";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import * as Font from "expo-font";

let customFonts = {
  "Bubblegum-Sans": require("../assets/fonts/BubblegumSans-Regular.ttf")
};

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fontsLoaded: false
    };
  }

  async _loadFontsAsync() {
    await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
    this.setState({
      fontsLoaded: true
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadFontsAsync();
  }

  isUserEqual = (googleUser, firebaseUser) => {
    if (firebaseUser) {
      var providerData = firebaseUser.providerData;
      for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
        if (
          providerData[i].providerId ===
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
          providerData[i].uid === googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId()
        ) {
          // We don't need to reauth the Firebase connection.
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  onSignIn = googleUser => {
    // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
    var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      unsubscribe();
      // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
      if (!this.isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
        // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
        var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          googleUser.idToken,
          googleUser.accessToken
        );

        // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then(function(result) {
            if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
              firebase
                .database()
                .ref("/users/" + user.uid)
                .set({
                  gmail: user.email,
                  profile_picture: additionalUserInfo.profile.picture,
                  locale: additionalUserInfo.profile.locale,
                  first_name: additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
                  last_name: additionalUserInfo.profile.family_name,
                })
                .then(function(snapshot) {});
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            // ...
          });
      } else {
        console.log("User already signed-in Firebase.");
      }
    });
  };

  signInWithGoogleAsync = async() => {
    try {
      const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        behaviour: "web",
        iosClientId: “My IOS Client ID",
        scopes: ["profile", "email"]
      });

      if (result.type === "success") {
        this.onSignIn(result);
        return result.accessToken;
      } else {
        return {
          cancelled: true
        };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
      return {
        error: true
      };
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.fontsLoaded) {
      return <AppLoading / > ;
    } else {
      return ( <
        View style = {
          styles.container
        } >
        <
        SafeAreaView style = {
          styles.droidSafeArea
        }
        />  <
        View style = {
          styles.appTitle
        } >
        <
        Image source = {
          require("../assets/logo.png")
        }
        style = {
          styles.appIcon
        } >
        <
        /Image> <
        Text style = {
          styles.appTitleText
        } > My App < /Text> < /
        View > <
        View style = {
          styles.buttonContainer
        } >
        <
        TouchableOpacity style = {
          styles.button
        }
        onPress = {
          () => this.signInWithGoogleAsync()
        } >
        <
        Image source = {
          require("../assets/google_icon.png")
        }
        style = {
          styles.googleIcon
        } >
        <
        /Image> <
        Text style = {
          styles.googleText
        } > Sign in with Google < /Text> < /
        TouchableOpacity > <
        /View> <
        View style = {
          styles.cloudContainer
        } >
        <
        Image source = {
          require("../assets/cloud.png")
        }
        style = {
          styles.cloudImage
        } >
        <
        /Image> < /
        View > <
        /View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#15193c"
  },
  droidSafeArea: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : RFValue(35)
  },
  appTitle: {
    flex: 0.4,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  appIcon: {
    width: RFValue(130),
    height: RFValue(130),
    resizeMode: "contain"
  },
  appTitleText: {
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: RFValue(40),
    fontFamily: "Bubblegum-Sans"
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 0.3,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  button: {
    width: RFValue(250),
    height: RFValue(50),
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: RFValue(30),
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  googleIcon: {
    width: RFValue(30),
    height: RFValue(30),
    resizeMode: "contain"
  },
  googleText: {
    color: "black",
    fontSize: RFValue(20),
    fontFamily: "Bubblegum-Sans"
  },
  cloudContainer: {
    flex: 0.3
  },
  cloudImage: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    resizeMode: "contain",
    bottom: RFValue(-5)
  }
});
```

EDIT: It's been 10 days since I posted this question, I would really appreciate having this answered soon. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove your iosClientId asap (from the question)

Comment: Thank you, just did that.